# The relationship between SelectionDAG and SelectionDAGISel

Tags: llvm

I am often confused about the relationship between SelectionDAG and SelectionDAGISel, also some other related classes as SelectionDAGLowering. Understanding their relationship in the high level would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to give you a couple of wonderful links to read about instruction selection:

- [Life of an instruction in LLVM by Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/11/24/life-of-an-instruction-in-llvm)
- [Instruction selection official documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#instruction-selection-section)

In a nutshell, `SelectionDAG` is a kind of internal representation with explicit instruction dependencies. It is used for instruction selection and scheduling ([DAG example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661529/what-does-machine-value-type-other-mean-in-llvm-sdnodes/26668737#26668737)).

`SelectionDAGISel` is a pass that converts machine independent LLVM IR into machine dependent representation (`MachineFunction`, `MachineBasicBlock`, `MachineInstr`), i.e. the pass builds `SelectionDAG` and performs instruction selection and scheduling. It is subclassed by specific targets, e.g. `ARMDAGToDAGISel`.

`SelectionDAGBuilder` is a class that builds `SelectionDAG` from LLVM IR.

I'm not sure about `SelectionDAGLowering`. It seems that it's the old name for `SelectionDAGBuilder` class.